# couldnt install wireless driver for ubuntu 12.04 in asus laptop

Tags: wireless, asus, ralink

i could not install the wireless driver in ubuntu 12.04 in Asus x45c laptop.
i already try all the methods in ubuntu forums. please someone help me..

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comment, so trying to help with answer.

Follow these instructions. Post the result. If there is any doubt in between you can check ubuntu help first. Once you know what's the actual problem, someone here can help to resolve it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WirelessTroubleshootingProcedure

Good luck. And next time get some more details to question so that someone can help easily. May be error log or at least links to methods you already tried.